# Need help in ID'ing a push button type

Tags: switches, identification, button

Can someone ID thing button for me?
I need to replace it and not sure what to buy.

It's burned out so i cannot with a meter to figure it out - it's not doing what it's suppose to.

[image]

Comment: You can take it apart to see. And question, is it a double action switch (as in you push it in half way, it does one thing, push it in harder/all the way, it does a second thing, like go faster?)

Comment: Also, the type/model/manufacturer of table would help. Is this a industrial table, used in an industry? Can you take the foot switch apart, as you would need to do it anyway?

Comment: Its a push button toggle switch rated at about 2A.   ON-COMMON-ON

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide an image of the mechanical side of the switch, so it's hard to say whether it is a slide or a toggle or another kind.

Because it has three terminals, it's probably a SPDT (single pole, double throw) switch. This means that it has a single "input" and two possible "outputs" depending on the position of the switch. (Or you can think of it as two inputs with one output, but the function is the same.)

The "N/O" markings mean "Normally Open" which would be commonly found on a momentary switch, meaning the switch contacts are open unless the switch is actuated. Without more information, it's hard to say what this means for this specific switch. My guess would be that the switch has a center position that is normally open, and you actuate the switch in one of two directions to connect to one or the other throw.

**Edit:**

Oops I missed that you said "button" in your text. If it's really a button, the N/O does not make sense. Since it is SPDT, the pole is connected to one throw in the disengaged position, and when pushed, the pole is connected to the other throw. There is no "normally open" about it.

Sometimes switches will have extra terminals that aren't connected (or placeholders for pins), so it's possible that the switch *is* normally open with an unused terminal, but the fact that all terminals in the photo have wires attached indicates to me that the "N/O" designation is probably false.

Comment: the other side is a button.. I cannot show it because the inside is inside a table stand and it's all covered with a metal cover that makes up a foot petal ..   it gets attached to a motor that rises a table and the other switch (with only two wires) lowers the table.. maybe thats helpful?

THANKS!

Comment: I cannot show all the wiring either because its inside the metal part of the table riser

Comment: Buttons are either momentary or push-on/push-off. If the button springs back after you release it, it's momentary. Look for a panel mount SPDT pushbutton switch that matches the action type of your existing button. Also measure the diameter of the panel opening, as you'll want to match it. Finally (and most importantly) make sure you select one with electrical ratings that meet or exceed what the switch is operating.

Comment: It's also possible that it's an illuminated switch. That would correlate well with the fact that it has three leads. Two for the switch, and a third for power.

Comment: thank you.
any good websites that has a nice variety of buttons?

Comment: It's not illuminated ... that would make sense, but it's just not.   

Its one of two buttons that ultimately lead to a motor. one button raises a table the other botton lowers it. The other botton has two poles two wires 

man I'm confused as to how the heck this is wired

Comment: IMPORTANT UODATE  (PHOTO UPDATED!!!!!!!!)

JUST realized the red wire is really white .. it's burned !!!

http://themezz.com/temp/id.jpg

Comment: @JYelton there are double or triple action push buttons, both momentary or push on/push off, and pull/push switches, and multiple combinations so it's not as simple as that.

Comment: @theMezz You might want to try [All Electronics](http://www.allelectronics.com), [DigiKey](http://www.digikey.com), or [Mouser](http://www.mouser.com). Connor is right, I forgot it could easily be an illuminated pushbutton. That would mean the switch is actually SPST and the third terminal is for power.

Comment: Re: the N/O markings : the lower one appears to be N/C on closer inspection, which makes more sense. (Can't be completely sure given the fuzzy photo) So it may be a latching pushbutton SPDT.